# Django - Load static files from another app

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-apps

In app1 I am trying to load static files from app2. I set no `STATICFILES_FINDERS` in project `settings.py`, which means, [Django will use default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders) `AppDirectoriesFinder` when it finds static subdirectory inside app directory.

**Problem**:

In template files of `app1`, I can generate urls of static files for app1 very easily. But if I want `app1` template files to generate urls for static files of `app2`, links are not working. How can I in `app1` generate static files of `app2`?

**App1 template file:**

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "app1/example.jpg" %}"> <!-- ok -->
<img src="{% static "app2/example.jpg" %}"> <!-- link broken -->
```

**HTML Output**:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/static/app1/example.jpg">
<img src="http://localhost:8000/static/app2/example.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Please be aware, that directory in your project folder, which is named exactly same as your project folder is **not** an app. At first thought it is the initial app, that is automatically created by Django, but it isnt.

If you have two apps, and you want to load static files between them, code examples above works.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I handled it setting this var in settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app1/static/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app2/static/'),
]
```

So, both dirs become avaliable in static template tag regardless from which app you're calling it.

I'm using django 2.1. 
Obs: 
1 - Maybe this come set by default when you use the startapp command. Idk.
2 - BASE_DIR is the abs path to settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your settings.py (from the Django documentation)

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    'var/www/static/',
]
```

Comment: Can you link where in the docs this is mentioned? Thanks!