# How can I add tailwind css to an existing django app

Tags: django, tailwind-css

I already have a Django project with many apps and one of them is demo_app. I have some views and templates added to the demo app but I want to start using tailwind in the demo_app templates. I have seen that to add tailwind I need to create the theme app using tailwind but I want to add it to the already existing demo_app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can create the theme app just like the documentation says and add the tags to your existing app. I followed the process in [this link](https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). The js config in the app already looks for the tailwind tags in other apps. The tags I used are
`{% load static tailwind_tags %}` and `{% tailwind_css %}`. I added them to the html template in my existing app.

`{% load static tailwind_tags %}` at the top of the template and `{% tailwind_css %}` in the `<head>`

Comment: This works locally, but once I deploy to production the stylesheet at `/static/css/dist/styles.css` which is included by `{% tailwind_css %}` doesn't exist since this folder only exists in the `theme` app. Any idea how to fix this? Should I simply change my `STATIC_URL` to point to the `theme` app `static` folder?

Comment: After further testing, it looks like `python manage.py collectstatic` does collect the tailwind css file in `theme`, but it is not accessible. 

When I create a `styles.css` in `my_app/static/styles.css` I'm able to load it in production with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">` but I am unable to load the stylesheet at `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/dist/styles.css">` generated by `{% tailwind_css %}`.

When I try to open the tailwind stylesheet in a new tab I get a `404`.

Comment: FYI - I was able to get this working by removing the `css/dist` directories in `package.json`. Removing `{% tailwind_css %}` and just linking to the stylesheet with `{% static 'styles.css' %}` after listing the theme static directory in the settings like suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51966704/1748562

Comment: Hello Maxim, I got the exact same problem. I deleted the `css/dist`in the `"build:clean"`, `"build:tailwind"` and `"build:dev"`. The location is `theme/static/styles.css`. But it still does not work. Could you specify your solution?

Comment: For me in production it worked with just running the collectstatic command, I am though using the django tailwind lib.

Answer (score 0):

What I did that worked for me was install tailwind-cli in the static folder of my Django app, check out the tailwind-cli installation guide [Tailwind Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation). And then load the CSS in the HTML template. Below is how I referenced the tailwind CSS.

```html
 {% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="{% static 'main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold">
    Hello, world!
  </h1>
  
</body>
</html>
```